# Multiple HTM5 regex in text field

Tags: html, regex

I'm trying to validate an entry in a text field via HTML5. Those are the rules:

- It can be empty;
- If not empty, it must be numeric and start with 21, 29 or 30;
- If starts with 21, it must have 13 characters;
- If starts with 29, it must have 15 characters;
- If starts with 30, it must have 16 characters;

I've got it partially working when I use:

```
<input type="text" pattern="NULL|^(21)[0-9]{1,13}" />
```

However, if I try to concatenate those rules, It only works for the first one.

```
<input type="text" pattern="NULL|^(21)[0-9]{1,13}|^(29)[0-9]{1,15}|^(30)[0-9]{1,16}" />
```

I'm aware it can be done via a Javascript function, however I'd like to use regex if possible.

Comment: `NULL` matches a *string* "NULL". Regex cannot detect null values.

Comment: If you are saying that it should have 13, 15 or 16 characters exactly depending on its initial number, why are you letting it have between one and the above-mentioned numbers?

Comment: Also, does *If starts with 21, it must have 13 characters* mean `21` is part of the total length restriction? So, `21` + 11 more *characters*? Do you mean *digits* (not *characters*) only?

Comment: Sorry, instead null, can be empty. Fixing my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
<input type="text" pattern="(?:21\d{11}|29\d{13}|30\d{14})?" />
```

The [HTML5 engine will wrap](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-pattern-attribute) it with `^(?:` and `)$` automatically. The regex will look like `^(?:(?:21\d{11}|29\d{13}|30\d{14})?)$` and will match

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `21\d{11}` - `21` and 11 digits
  - `|` - or
  - `29\d{13}`  - `29` and 13 digits
  - `|` - or
  - `30\d{14}` - `30` and 14 digits
- `)?` - end of the group, repeat 1 or 0 times
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Good point on using `\d` for more readability and simplicity.

Answer (score 4):

There are the two mentioned problems. First, to match an empty input that I assume it is what you want you need to use the `^$` constructor.

Then if you want to limit the required length of the input you need to state the proper length, not a variable one.

A regex like this one should work:

```
^$|^(21)[0-9]{11}$|^(29)[0-9]{13}$|^(30)[0-9]{14}$
```

The numbers inside the curly brackets indicate the length of the numeric characters behind the 21, 29 and 30. Those will depend on whether you are counting those as two characters or not for the proper length.

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/rW6bEB/1/) and see some examples.

Comment: For sure yours is a much cleaner solution that should be taken as reference. I just posted a working one based on the one provided by the question's example. Great answer @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Ok, redundancy won't harm. Just HTML5 patterns are always anchored, that is why you can often do without explicit anchors there.